# Where to find the debuginfo kernel rpm for ubuntu 12.04 ?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, systemtap, debug-information

I am trying to run systamtap on ubuntu and i have the default ubuntu 12.04 without any debuginfo package installed on it.

I am getting below error:

semantic error: missing x86_64 kernel/module debuginfo [man warning::debuginfo] under '/lib/modules/3.8.0-35-generic/build'

Can someone guide me with how i can enable debuginfo on my system ?  I only find packages related to fedora or rhel.

Also do i require compiling kernel with the debuginfo ?

I found this useful link from ubuntu :
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/debuginfo-install.1.html

but when i try 
sudo debuginfo-install kernel i get 
No debuginfo packages available to install

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone is using this, I didnt get any help but figured out how to install debuginfo

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ECDCAD72428D7C01
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```